# Do any rails authentication gems implement the secure salted hashing outlined here: crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication

I'm trying to select a rails login/authentication gem that implements a strong salted hashing algorithm using the best practice methods outlined at this site:

http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Do you know which Rails gems which can support full login / logout / password recovery + these hashing requirements?

Comment: veritas1: Thanks for pointing me to an implementation of bcrypt - that's helpful. So is there a complete auth kit (like Devise) that supports best practice hashing?  (Note: Devise may already support this - I'm just not sure).

Comment: Note: There's a long check list of requirements and lots of 'bad ways to do it' at ...
  http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

I'm trying to find an authentication kit that complies with all of these requirements.  You need to read all of it to see the big picture - not just skim the first section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the `has_secure_password` class method.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Here is a railscast on it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Comment: Thanks bcrypt support should solve part of the problem. Now I just need to identify a complete auth kit that supports login, logout, password recover, etc that uses best practice hashing.